# ceph df showing available space which doesn't match ceph partition size

Tags: ceph, linux-disk-free

I just noticed a backfillfull osd warning in our ceph cluster and there is something really strange in how `ceph osd df` is showing available space.

If I try to look at ceph' storage partition with `df -h`

```
# df -h | grep ceph
/dev/mapper/cl-var_lib_ceph    2.0G   57M  1.8G   4% /var/lib/ceph
/dev/mapper/cl-var_local_ceph   50G   11G   40G  21% /var/local/ceph
```

We can see 40G available. Now if I run `ceph osd df`

```
# ceph osd df
ID CLASS WEIGHT  REWEIGHT SIZE   USE    AVAIL %USE  VAR  PGS 
 2   hdd 0.00980  1.00000 10240M  9220M 1019M 90.04 1.00  40 
 0   hdd 0.00980  1.00000 10240M  9229M 1010M 90.13 1.00  40 
 1   hdd 0.00980  1.00000 10240M  9242M  997M 90.26 1.00  40 
                    TOTAL 30720M 27691M 3028M 90.14          
MIN/MAX VAR: 1.00/1.00  STDDEV: 0.09
```

Size is only 10240M, why is it so and how can I tell ceph to get size from the partition (50G) ?

Answer (score -3):

please use a below command :

## ceph df

for displaye available space.